# MacOS Mojave Xcode 10 + OpenGL not drawn after init window

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, glfw, xcode10

I have encountered a problem with Xcode 10 when I run OpenGL GLFW and GLEW c++ code. The windows do init but the drawing is hidden before I tried to move the window frame by mouse. How can I solve this problem?

[Before I move window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTn9D.png)

[After I move window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyltK.png)

Comment: It works now without the workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/1334) which is now solved at [GLFW's source repository](https://github.com/glfw/glfw)

Comment: @NientaiHo: Can you expand on what makes it inelegant?

Comment: My workaround is using below in the drawing loop -------------------------
   `glfwShowWindow(window);
    glfwHideWindow(window);
    glfwShowWindow(window);`

Comment: @NientaiHo, you mean that the solution I suggested is not elegant because it requires using the latest not-yet-released version of GLFW??

Comment: I mean the issue is rooted in Xcode 10 so there is only temp fix

Comment: @NientaiHo: Do you mean that you expect that the issue will be resolved in a future Xcode update?

Comment: I hope Xcode will keep OpenGL though Metal is their main focus

Answer (score 1):

SDL had a similar problem, see this change for their (current) fix:

https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/rev/86dcfbbcacaf

Comment: Any c++ version of solution?